# GRUB не видит установленную windows 10

Tags: debian, windows-10, boot

По работе возникла необходимость накатить debian 8 jessie рядом с windows 10.
Отщепил 100гб от диска, которые и использовал при установке дебиана. Дошел до момента, когда необходмо установить GRUB, где было следующее:

Похоже, что данная система будет единственной на данном компьютере. Если это действительно так, то можно спокойно устанавливать системный загрузчик GRUB в основную загрузочную запись первого жесткого диска. Установить GRUB в главную загрузочную запись?

При нажатии на "нет", предлагается выбрать либо /dev/sda (где, насколько я понял, находится винда), или /dev/sdb (загрузочая флешка) и можно указать вручную

Если выбирать /dev/sda, то при перезагрузке грузится винда. В UEFI в разделе boot могу выбрать или винду, или флешку. То есть, получается, что debian как бы есть, но попасть я в него не могу.

Подскажите, как поступить?

Answer (score 1):

Кусок винта который отцепили для установки должен быть не размечен (светится черным в винде), попробуйте установить дистрибутив поновой, если не поможет заходите в винду (после установки дистрибутива), запускаете cmd от имени администратора вводим `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` (пример для убунту поправьте для своего дистрибутива) и перезапустить комп, должен появится GRUB, если не появился опять в командную строку винды `bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` (удаление) `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi` (добавление)

Comment: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` не помогло: все равно загрузилась винда.
`bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi` пишет: Недопустимая команда удаления

Comment: @ASh там надо путь поправить для важего дистрибутува, для дебиана будет другой путь (уже не помнб какой а искать лень), так же удостовертесь что все правильно сделали ([готовая инструкция по установке](http://mydebianblog.blogspot.com/2006/08/in-true-debian-way.html))

Comment: я поправил. Ошибся в комментарии выше. Судя по [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI) эти пути идентичные, с заменой ubuntu на debian

Comment: @ASh ну эти команды должны помочь, недавно сам рядом с виндой ставил Kali, тоже игрался долго)